# I need to truncate and replace data in a table that is frequently being queried

Tags: sql-server, jobs

## Primary Question:

I want to truncate and refresh a table in SQL Server, but want to wait until any queries currently accessing the table to finish.  Is this a simple setting in SQL Server, or do I need to create some logic to accomplish it?

### Detailed Description:

I have a VB application that sits on about 300 terminals.  The application calls a SqlServer(2008 R2) stored procedure ([spGetScreenData]) every 2 minutes to get the latest sales data.
[spGetScreenData] creates a series of temp tables and returns a select query of about 200 rows and 100 columns.  It takes about 8 seconds to execute.

My goal is to create a new stored procedure ([spRefreshScreenData]) that executes every two minutes which will refresh the data in a table ([SCREEN_DATA]).  I will then change [spGetScreenData] to simply query [SCREEN_DATA].

The job that refreshes [SCREEN_DATA] first sets a flag in a status table to 'RUNNING' while it executes.  Once complete, it sets that status to 'COMPLETED'.

[spGetScreenData] checks the status of the flag before querying and waits (for a period of time) until it's ready.  Something like...

```
DECLARE @Condition AS BIT=0
,       @Count AS INT=0
,       @CycleCount AS INT=10 --10 cycles (20 Seconds)

WHILE @Condition = 0 AND @Count < @CycleCount
BEGIN
    SET @Count = @Count + 1

    IF EXISTS(  SELECT  Status 
                FROM    tbl_Process_Status
                WHERE   Process = 'POS_Table_Refresh' 
                AND     Status='Running')
            WAITFOR DELAY '000:00:02' --Wait 2 seconds
        ELSE
            SET @Condition=1
END

SELECT *
FROM SCREEN_DATA
WHERE (Store=@Store OR @Store IS NULL)
```

My concern has to do with [spRefreshScreenData].  When [spRefeshScreenData] begins its truncation, there could be dozens of requests for the data currently running.

Will SqlServer simply wait until the request are done before truncating?  Is there a setting I have to set to not mess these queries up?

Or do I have to build some mechanism to wait until all requests are completed before starting the truncation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The job that refreshes [SCREEN_DATA] first sets a flag in a status table to 'RUNNING' while it executes. Once complete, it sets that status to 'COMPLETED'.
>
> [spGetScreenData] checks the status of the flag before querying and waits (for a period of time) until it's ready

Don't. Use app locks. The readers (`spGetScreenData`) are the app lock in shared mode, the writers (refresh job) requests it X mode. See [`sp_getapplock`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189823.aspx).

But even this is no necessary. You can build the new data online, while the queries continue, w/o affecting them using a *staging* table, ye a different table than the one queried by the apps. When the rebuild is complete simply swap the original tabel with the staging one, using either fast SWITCH operations (see [Transferring Data Efficiently by Using Partition Switching](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191160(v=sql.105).aspx)) or using the good 'ole [`sp_rename`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188351.aspx) trick.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply.     


So I understand, are you saying that [spRefreshScreenData] should request an exclusive app lock, perform the data refresh, then release the lock?  

The lock won't be granted until all current [spGetScreenData] calls are completed, and also any new [spGetScreenData] requests that happen during the data refresh will have to wait until the lock is released?

And the partition switch concept can be used in [spRefreshScreenData] to make the refresh go quickly?

Comment: Is either applock (and the will work as you described) or switch trick. With the switch trick there is no need for explicit app lock, the readers will see either the 'old' table or the 'new' one (the switch is atomic).

Comment: you do not need to release the applock, it will be released when you commit. use transactions and bind the applock to them (both for reads and for writes).